# Angular 1.5 and multiple nested data structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, optimization, data-structures

I have got a nested structure which looks like this example:

```
let structure = [{
  section: '1',
  title: 'First lvl title',
  children: [{
    section: '1.1',
    title: 'Second lvl title',
    children: []
  }, {
    section: '1.2',
    title: 'Second lvl title',
    children: [{
      section: '1.2.1',
      title: 'Third lvl title',
      children: []
    }, {
      section: '1.2.2',
      title: 'Third lvl title',
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    section: '1.3',
    title: 'Second lvl title',
    children: []
  }]
}, {
  section: '2',
  title: 'First lvl title',
  children: [{
    section: '2.1',
    title: 'Second lvl title',
    children: []
  }, {
    section: '2.2',
    title: 'Second lvl title',
    children: []
  }]
}, ...other objects]
```

As you can see, structure is similar to the table of contents - I have got objects which represents units and each unit has own section number, title and array with subsections.

Data characteristic is that I never know how many sections and how many nested subsections I have. I need to assume that I can get something around 2 000 objects (maybe more) with different configuration. Also, I cannot predict maximum nested level and it can be different for specific sections.

I am trying to find the most optimized way to represent this structure as HTML page. I am thinking about using ng-repeat but I don't know if it is a good idea since I don't know how many deep levels I will have. Also, after generating my HTML page, I can remove one section (for example section 1) and I need to recalculate section numbers for each other section and subsection (section 2 is now section 1, subsection 2.1 is now subsection 1.1, and so on). What is the best way to handle this operation on such a big amount of data?

Comment: Hmmm, 2000 objects. I think Angular is not gonna like 2000 bindings. ng-repeat will put a watch on the array. So anything that is added or removed will be reflected in your view. ng-if can take care of the unpredictability in your data.

Comment: A user can't absorb that much in the first place. You will need some recursive templating but you also need to figure out ways to filter or paginate that much data. As @Mikey pointed out there will also be performance problems ... 2000 objects will have multiples x 2000 bindings

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a recursive template, wherein it won't matter what the structure is nor how many levels deep the data go. You can use a recursive custom directive or recursive ngInclude:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
    {{ category.title }}
    <ul ng-if="category.categories">
        <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Comment: Recursive templates is an interesting idea but I am not sure if I need ng-repeat for the loop. Using _ng-repeat loop_ can be costly since it is creating new binding and maybe I should use _for loop_ instead.